# react-bootstrap navbar odd behavior

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

So I just dived into the react-bootstrap library today to implement a navbar.

The page with code and demo I looked into: https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/navbar/#navbars-mobile-friendly

Notice how the examples are already nicely styled. I tried doing pretty much the same, but it looks depressing and unstyled at all, not even the bg is working.

My code:

```
import React from "react";
import {Nav, Navbar} from 'react-bootstrap'
import './style.css';
import logo from '../../assets/logo.png';

function LoginNav() {
    return (
        <Navbar expand="lg" bg="dark" variant="dark">
            <Navbar.Brand>
                <img id="logo"
                    className="d-inline-block align-top"
                    src={logo} alt="logo"
                />
            </Navbar.Brand>
            <Navbar.Collapse id="basic-navbar-nav">
                <Nav className="mr-auto">
                    <Nav.Link href="#home">Login</Nav.Link>
                    <Nav.Link href="#link">Link</Nav.Link>
                </Nav>
            </Navbar.Collapse>
        </Navbar>
    );
};

export default LoginNav;
```

My CSS doesn't do anything other than resizing the logo, and I did yarn add react-bootstrap as well as npm i --save react-bootstrap already. I have no idea why it is not working. Any insight can help! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Without errors for us to look at, there is not much to go off of. I would start with checking where you are importing the LoginNav to. if the `<Navbar></Navbar>` is a container level element and you are inserting it into a row or col level it may be causing formatting issues.

***Update 5-15-2020***

You stated the above code is all you have and if so you need to add your Navbar to existing HTML or create a new React App. Either way the info is here https://reactjs.org/.

I was able to run your code just fine and it worked. I changed the bg from dark to light just to see if it changed, and it did.

The commands below will create a React App, and will start the node server environment. Run the commands in console, in a directory you want the app saved. The 'my-app' at the end of the first command is going to be the name of your App. So it can be whatever you want, and 'npx' isn't a typo.

npx create-react-app my-app
cd my-app
npm start

The code below is how I used the Navbar and it displayed just fine. If you already have all this set up, try and put the style sheet import right before the ReactDOM.render() in index.js

***Update*** 
Is this how your file set-up looks?

```
//index.html

< !DOCTYPE html >
    <html lang="en">
        <head>
            // loads of stuff here, taken out for shorthand. Not important for the example 
            // but important for the overall project to work and is included when you create
            // the app. Plus any additional things you add
        </head>
        <body>
            <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
            <div id="root"></div>
        </body>
</html>
```

```
//index.js

import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import App from './fileLocation'
//import style sheet here and see if that helps with formatting 

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

```
//App.js

import React, { Component } from 'react'
import LoginNav from './fileLocation'

class App extends Component {
     render(){
           return (<LoginNav />);
     }
}
export default App
```

Comment: What I had is literally my entire code and I have no idea why it's not doing anything :(

Comment: Where are you using the LoginNav() function? You created it and exported it, but we can not see where it is being used. This can not be all the code you have. If so, that is the problem.

Comment: I just rendered it in App.js  byi itself without any containers, and App.js was also the only thing rendered by index.js. I tried just doing a basic nav bar without using bootstrap and it apparently works well... And yeah, this application was created by create-react-app